# How to play video in landscape mode from one landscape to another landscape in Android

Tags: android, video, orientation, landscape

Here i develop one application which play video in only landscape mode. i set my activity orientation to "landscape" in AndroidManifest.xml file. and my video is playing very nice but problem is that i hold my device in Landscape mode i rotate my device to 180 angle my video playing show inverse (bottom to top). it not chaging according to that.

Comment: check your activity orientation...

Comment: i edit my question more describly please help